# Credentials errors setting up aws opsworks on instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I am trying to set up opsworks on a Ubuntu EC2 instance for monitoring logs. I am at the stage of registering my instance with Opsworks. The command I have been give to register is (with x's inserted to protect information)

```
aws opsworks register --use-instance-profile --infrastructure-class ec2 --region xx-west-xx --stack-id xxxxxxx-fe9c-xxxxx-99f8-xxxxxxx --local
```

however when I run this command the install fails with the error

```
/opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:100:in `require_credentials': unable to sign request without credentials set (Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
```

This would suggest I do not have my aws credentials set, but I have both my ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY set in ~/.aws/credentials, I have also tried exporting both of these variables as environment variables but I still receive the same error. Any idea why this could be happening?

Here is the full output

```
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:33:32 +0000] installer-wrapper: Using opsworks-instance-assets-us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com for assets.
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:33:32 +0000] installer-wrapper: Skipping installation of opsworks-agent-ruby because it's already installed
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:33:32 +0000] installer-wrapper: Cleaning up
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:33:32 +0000] opsworks-init: Starting the installer
/opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:100:in `require_credentials': unable to sign request without credentials set (Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:90:in `sign_authenticated_requests'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:83:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:87:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/handler.rb:11:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:41:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/registration.rb:136:in `register_instance'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/registration.rb:55:in `merge_agent_config'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/registration.rb:14:in `block in generate_agent_config'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/registration.rb:13:in `open'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/registration.rb:13:in `generate_agent_config'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/instance_agent_registration_installer.rb:29:in `block in run'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/log.rb:96:in `measure'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/instance_agent_registration_installer.rb:29:in `run'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/lib/bootstrap/instance_agent_registration_installer.rb:11:in `run'
    from /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.31Gl4pMnG52hqBgo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/bin/opsworks-agent-registration-installer.rb:8:in `<main>'
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:35:18 +0000] opsworks-init: Agent installation failed.
[Wed, 01 Jul 2020 01:35:18 +0000] opsworks-init: Please verify the log files found under /var/log/aws/opsworks and submit findings to AWS Support.
```

Comment: Usually you would put required permission in the instance role. Have you tried that?

Comment: I haven't, is that on my instance or in aws?

Comment: Yes, you attach the role to the instance. More details about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into this error

```
/opt/aws/opsworks/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:100:in `require_credentials': unable to sign request without credentials set (Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
```

> This would suggest I do not have my aws credentials set, but I have
> both my `ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set in ~/.aws/credentials,
> I have also tried exporting both of these variables as environment
> variables but I still receive the same error. Any idea why this could
> be happening?

First thing, you should not use `ACCESS_KEY_ID` while you working inside AWS, better to use [EC2 instance role](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20attach%20or,%2C%20distributes%2C%20and%20rotates%20automatically.).

Second thing, its mean that the above keys does not have the permission to register instance with AWS opswork stack.

You need to add required permission to add instance in ops work stack.you can use below permission to make it work.

```
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "opsworks:RegisterInstance", 
            "opsworks:DeregisterInstance",
            "opsworks:DescribeInstances"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

[registered-instance-with-opswork](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register-registering-template.html)

Comment: No, you need to add this in the instance IAM role, you can read more here to create role and assign permission https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html or you can assign this role for which you created keys but I will not recommend this approch

Comment: Just needed to add "opsworks:RegisterInstance" and it worked perfectly, thanks for the help

Comment: Perfect, I updated accordingly, the dregister will help in future